# Mysql read replica slow for some queries

Tags: mysql, indexing, amazon-rds

We have a master-slave setup in AWS RDS using mysql. We have a `db.m4.xlarge` for both of the instances. One of the tables is performing very slow on the read replica.

**Table** - user_exercises

**Table Size** - 3.9GB

**Rows** - 273499

**Query** - select count(*) from user_exercises;

The table has a primary key only as an index. On the master it takes < 0.1 second. On the read replica it runs forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is the Query cache turned on?  That may explain why the Primary ran so fast.
- Adding a secondary index on some small column will speed up the query.  Yeah, it is a kludge -- The Optimizer will pick the smallest index for doing `SELECT COUNT(*)`.
- 3.9GB/273K -- sounds like the table has a big text column?

Comment: Even the `select count(id)` has the same behaviour. `id` is the PK in the table.
Yes the table has a text column which we need to optimise once we solve the current blockages.

Comment: The cache settings look similar for both the instances. Any particular setting that I may look for?

Comment: @Harshit - Let's move forward into the other optimizations.  Meanwhile think ways to get an approximation to the count, not the exact count in real-time.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick. I added some indices in the table and now the read replica is acting normal. One strange thing I noticed was that the add index ran in < 3 seconds on master but to replicate on the read replica it kept on running for about 4-5 minutes.

Comment: @Harshit - Perhaps there are more `SELECTs` on the replica, and they are interfering more with the `ADD INDEX`?  What version?

Comment: version is 5.6.40 on AWS RDS. Also I ran the queries when the traffic to the read replica was cut off.

Comment: Has this Q&A morphed from `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `ALTER TABLE`?  Those are too different to discuss in a single thread.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought of mentioning the observations I had. The original question had already been answered, thanks a lot for that.